# Javascript Menu - How to redirect link to another webpage

Tags: javascript, css

I am familiar with html/css navigation coding. But I can't seem to get one of the links in my clients menu navigation to redirect to her blog. I know in html you can use target="_blank". But I can't seem to figure how to redirect in javascript.

This is the html I have for the menu:

```
<div id="menu">
    <script>setMenuOption('home');</script>
</div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
function setMenuOption(pageID) {

    if (pageID == 'home') {
        reset();
        return;
    }

    if (pageID == 'about') {
        document.write("<a href='index.html'>HOME</a>");
        document.write("<a class='active'>ABOUT AVP</a>");
        document.write("<a href='services.html'>SERVICES</a>");
        document.write("<a href='affiliates.html'>AFFILIATES</a>");
        document.write("<a href='gallery.html'>GALLERY</a>");
        document.write("<like href='whatsnew.html'>WHAT'S NEW</a>");
        document.write("<a href='contact.html'>CONTACT</a>");
    }

    if (pageID == 'services') {
        document.write("<a href='index.html'>HOME</a>");
        document.write("<a href='about.html'>ABOUT AVP</a>");
        document.write("<a class='active'>SERVICES</a>");
        document.write("<a href='affiliates.html'>AFFILIATES</a>");
        document.write("<a href='gallery.html'>GALLERY</a>");
        document.write("<a href='whatsnew.html'>WHAT'S NEW</a>");
        document.write("<a href='contact.html'>CONTACT</a>");
    }


    if (pageID == 'affiliates') {
        document.write("<a href='index.html'>HOME</a>");
        document.write("<a href='about.html'>ABOUT AVP</a>");
        document.write("<a href='services.html'>SERVICES</a>");
        document.write("<a class='active'>AFFILIATES</a>");
        document.write("<a href='gallery.html'>GALLERY</a>");
        document.write("<a href='whatsnew.html'>WHAT'S NEW</a>");
        document.write("<a href='contact.html'>CONTACT</a>");
    }

    if (pageID == 'gallery') {
        document.write("<a href='index.html'>HOME</a>");
        document.write("<a href='about.html'>ABOUT AVP</a>");
        document.write("<a href='services.html'>SERVICES</a>");
        document.write("<a href='affiliates.html'>AFFILIATES</a>");
        document.write("<a class='active'>GALLERY</a>");
        document.write("<a href='whatsnew.html'>WHAT'S NEW</a>");
        document.write("<a href='contact.html'>CONTACT</a>");
    }

    if (pageID == 'whatsnew') {
        document.write("<a href='index.html'>HOME</a>");
        document.write("<a href='about.html'>ABOUT AVP</a>");
        document.write("<a href='services.html'>SERVICES</a>");
        document.write("<a href='affiliates.html'>AFFILIATES</a>");
        document.write("<a href='gallery.html'>GALLERY</a>");
        document.write("<a class='active'>WHAT'S NEW</a>");
        document.write("<a href='contact.html'>CONTACT</a>");
    }

    if (pageID == 'contact') {
        document.write("<a href='index.html'>HOME</a>");
        document.write("<a href='about.html'>ABOUT AVP</a>");
        document.write("<a href='services.html'>SERVICES</a>");
        document.write("<a href='affiliates.html'>AFFILIATES</a>");
        document.write("<a href='gallery.html'>GALLERY</a>");
        document.write("<a href='whatsnew.html'>WHAT'S NEW</a>");
        document.write("<a class='active'>CONTACT</a>");
    }

    if (pageID == 'footer') {
        document.write("<a href='index.html'>HOME</a>");
        document.write("<a href='about.html'>ABOUT AVP</a>");
        document.write("<a href='services.html'>SERVICES</a>");
        document.write("<a href='affiliates.html'>AFFILIATES</a>");
        document.write("<a href='gallery.html'>GALLERY</a>");
        document.write("<a href='whatsnew.html'>WHAT'S NEW</a>");
        document.write("<a href='contact.html'>CONTACT</a>");
    }
}

function reset() {

    document.write("<a href='about.html'>ABOUT AVP</a>");
    document.write("<a href='services.html'>SERVICES</a>");
    document.write("<a href='affiliates.html'>AFFILIATES</a>");
    document.write("<a href='gallery.html'>GALLERY</a>");
    document.write("<a href='whatsnew.html'>WHAT'S NEW</a>");
    document.write("<a href='contact.html'>CONTACT</a>");
}
```

I am trying to redirect the "whatsnew" page to my clients blog... https://ashleyvictoriaproductions.wordpress.com/ .

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Yow. You're using jQuery, yet you're still using `document.write`? That's wrong on several levels.

Comment: Are you asking how to set the `href` value in the link, or how to do some sort of page change dynamically?

Comment: see my comment in my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Tryed this?

```
document.write("<a href='https://ashleyvictoriaproductions.wordpress.com/' target='_blank'>WHAT'S NEW</a>");
```

Comment: I copy and pasted the code in all instances in my "menu.js". I uploaded the file and tested the links. It still redirects to "whatsnew.html".

Comment: I bet you replaced only one row 
        document.write("<like href='whatsnew.html'>WHAT'S NEW</a>");..

Comment: you should replace 'whatsnew.html' to --> https://ashleyvictoriaproductions.wordpress.com/ in all parts of your menu.js

Answer (score 0):

Add class to your link

```
document.write("<a class='whatsNew' href='whatsnew.html'>WHAT'S NEW</a>");
```

And then jQuery

```
$('.whatsNew').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   window.location.href = "https://ashleyvictoriaproductions.wordpress.com/";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For redirecting in plain JS:

```js
window.location.href = "https://ashleyvictoriaproductions.wordpress.com/"
```

If i understand your question correctly though, you just need to replace the relative link "whatsnew.html" in:

```js
document.write("<a href='whatsnew.html'>WHAT'S NEW</a>");
```

with the blog url:

```js
document.write("<a href='https://ashleyvictoriaproductions.wordpress.com/' target='_blank'>WHAT'S NEW</a>");
```

Comment: I tried replacing the "whatsnew.html" with the blog link, but no success.

Comment: in the code you provided, the second if block `if(pageID=='about')` has an error in the respective `document.write` call. Instead of `<a...` you have `<like...`. Maybe you are checking it on the about page and that's what's causing the error?

Comment: Thank you!!! Also just realized I didn't upload the new menu.js file. Stupid mistake. But thanks for the catch!

Comment: No problemo. Glad I could help :-)